# binary or contiuous image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have an image which I want to use it in MATLAB. But, I am looking for a method by which I be able to automatically find that my image is binary (0 and 1) or continuous. Is there any solution of piece of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question I'm guessing you are dealing only with images of the logical or double class. The first should be used for real binary images but unfortunately, that's not always the case when using code out in the wild.

It seems to me your problem is to distinguish between a real image of double class (all values between 0 and 1) or a binary image as class double (all values are 0 or 1). The best way to do it is the following which returns true if the image only has the values 1 and 0:

```
bool = all ((image(:) == 1) + (image(:) == 0));
```

This is a line from `isbw()` in Octave image package where you can use `isbw (img, "non-logical")`

Answer (score 6):

For starters you cannot formally talk about binary or continuous images. Digital images have a discrete set of values, taken from a finite value set depending on their format and pixel bit-wise representation.

For example a "binary" image would have 2 levels of gray (white and black), represented by 0 or 1 or any other combination of values, e.g. an image of levels 0, 255 is still "binary". A  grayscale image for an 8-bit representation (i.e. 8 bits per pixel) will have `2^8` discrete levels of intensity from `min` 0 (black) to `max` 255 (white).

Thus you can test for the number of unique levels of gray, i.e. unique values in your input image:

```
I = imread(image_filename); 
if length(unique(I))==2, 
    flag_binary = true 
end
```

**Examples**:

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
>> disp(flag_binary)
     0
I = imread('circles.png');
>> disp(flag_binary)
     1
```

Comment: @ Gevang: I have two images: (0 and 1) and a gray scale image (continuous), in this case the above codes does not work. I mean, I am looking for a method by which be able to discrete that my image is categorical or gray scale. Definitely, in gray scale, similar to binary (0,1), I have a just one bound.

Comment: @Sam: "does not work" --> how does it fail? gevang just showed it works for a grayscale **and** binary image

Comment: Perhaps use `if size(img,3)~=1 && numel(unique(I))==2` or even `if ndims(I)==2 && islogical(I)`...would that work?

Comment: I have two matrix: the first one is compose of only 1 and 0 and the second one is between 0 and 256. I want to distinguish between them. Binary or continuous!

Comment: @Sam : You can use flag_binary above to distinguish between them. For your first image `flag_binary` will be 0 (false), for the second one `flag_binary` will be 1 (true). In pseudocode: `if flag_binary then binary <- image; else continuous <- image`

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the histogram using `imhist`. If there are more than two distinct grayvalues in the histogram your image is not binary.